# Using Abstract or Interface with Inner or "Dependent" Class

Tags: java, interface, matrix, abstract

I find myself repeatedly making a "Matrix" class with a 2D array of "Cell" objects (the "dependent" class from my title, not sure if there is a standard term for this, a class that is external, but only accessed from class that calls its constructor and methods). So of course, I am looking to build myself some reusable classes and/or interfaces.

The matrix looks like this:

```
public class Matrix {

private Cell matrix[][];
private float spaceWidth, spaceHeight;
private int xCols, yRows;

public Matrix(int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height){
    matrix = populateCells(xCols,yRows);
    spaceWidth = width / xCols;
    spaceHeight = height / yRows;
    this.xCols = xCols;
    this.yRows = yRows;
}

public Cell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) {
    Cell c[][] = new Cell[xCols][yRows];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < xCols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < yRows; j++){
            c[i][j] = new Cell(i,j,k);
            k++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
...
}

public class Cell {
private int x, y, num;

public Cell(int x, int y, int num, String name){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.num = num;
}

public float getX(){return x;}
public float getY(){return y;}
public int getNum(){return num;}
}
```

I want every Cell and every Matrix to have these properties. The problem comes when I want to extend Cell to add properties.  No matter what combination of interface and/or abstract I try, I can't seem to figure out how to extend Matrix and Cell without rewriting Matrix.populateCells verbatim, with just the new Cell name. In other words, I want to extend Cell without breaking every reference to it in Matrix.

So basically, how do I organize this so that abstraction does what it's supposed to do, i.e., limit duplicate code, encapsulate, etc.?

---

Just to summarize my implementation of the selected answer:

```
public interface ICell {

public abstract int getX();
public abstract int getY();
public abstract int getNum();

}

public class Cell implements ICell {
private int x, y, num;

public Cell(int x, int y, int num){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.num = num;
}

    //getters...
}

public class WaveCell extends Cell implements ICell {
private boolean marked;

public WaveCell(int x, int y, int num) {
    super(x, y, num);
    marked = false;
}

public boolean isMarked() {return marked;}
public void setMarked(boolean marked) {this.marked = marked;}

    // More new stuff...    
}

public class WaveMatrix extends Matrix {

public WaveMatrix(int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height) {
    super(xCols, yRows, width, height);
}

@Override
public ICell newCell(int i, int j, int k){
    ICell c = new WaveCell(i,j,k);
    return c;
}
    ...
 }

 public class Matrix {

private ICell matrix[][];
private float spaceWidth, spaceHeight;
int xCols, yRows;

public Matrix(int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height){
    matrix = populateCells(xCols,yRows);
    spaceWidth = width / xCols;
    spaceHeight = height / yRows;
    this.xCols = xCols;
    this.yRows = yRows;
}

public ICell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) {
    ICell c[][] = new ICell[xCols][yRows];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < xCols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < yRows; j++){
            c[i][j] = newCell(i,j,k);
            k++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

public ICell newCell(int i, int j, int k){
    ICell c = new Cell(i,j,k);
    return c;
}
    ...
}
```

Comment: "private public Cell matrix[][];" .... wat?  Just to clarify, you're asking how to create a hierarchy of Cell, where Cell is the parent class, and you're able to adopt further children of Cell, like RedBloodCell... All without changing your PopulateCells method?

Comment: Private/public fixed. It's not that I don't want to _change_ populateCells, but I don't want to call super and loop through the array, and then do it again in the child. Is there a way to pass a type as a parameter, maybe?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use generics, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: For a concrete example, say I want the extended Cell, let's say TargetCell to have a boolean "hit." I can set this as false by default in the class definition, so it need not come up in populateCells, I just need the one word "Cell" to be changed. I can get mostly there by returning an "ICell" interface, but cell is still there in the constructor in the middle of the loop.

Comment: Pass a type as a parameter? You could create a HashTable of all of your possible cells: (private Hashtable<Integer, Class<Cell>> allMyCellTypes;) Then make a class constructor call from the HashTable... It'll be tricky.

Comment: Looks like the problem is your `public Cell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows)` method. Sounds like you shouldn't have method that constructs the Cell objects in the Matrix class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not that I don't want to change populateCells, but I don't want to call super and loop through the array, and then do it again in the child.

In case you want to be able to extend `Matrix` in a way that you can do extra steps in `populateCells` you can simply move parts of that into methods that you can override. Like in code below

```
public class Matrix {

    public Cell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) {
        Cell c[][] = new Cell[xCols][yRows];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xCols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < yRows; j++){
                c[i][j] = getCell(i,j,k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public Cell getCell(int i, int j, int k) {
        return new Cell(i, j, k);
    }

}


class SuperMatrix extends Matrix {
    @Override
    public Cell getCell(int i, int j, int k) {
        Cell c = super.getCell(i, j, k);
        modify(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```

---

You can also use above with the same strategy pattern as suggested by @Perception. The difference is that in below code just a single `ICell` is produced while in the other example the complete array of cells would be the product.

```
public class Matrix {
    /** a common cell interface */
    public interface ICell {
        public int getX();
        public int getY();
    }

    /** somthing that knows how to produce a cell */
    public interface CellProducerStrategy {
        public ICell getCell(int i, int j, int k);
    }

    /** method of Matrix that is always the same for all Cells and Strategies */
    public ICell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows, CellProducerStrategy strategy) {
        ICell c[][] = new ICell[xCols][yRows];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xCols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < yRows; j++){
                c[i][j] = strategy.getCell(i,j,k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    // ---------- some implementation --------------------

    static class DefaultCell implements ICell {
        public DefaultCell(int i, int j, int k) {
            // something
        }
        @Override
        public int getX() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getY() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class DefaultCellProducer implements CellProducerStrategy {
        @Override
        public ICell getCell(int i, int j, int k) {
            return new DefaultCell(i, j, k);
        }
    }

    // ---------- alternative implementation --------------------

    static class NamedCell implements ICell {
        private String name;
        public NamedCell(int i, int j, int k, String name) {
            // something
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public int getX() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getY() {
            return 0;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public static class NamedCellProducer implements CellProducerStrategy {
        @Override
        public ICell getCell(int i, int j, int k) {
            return new NamedCell(i, j, k, "John-" + i*j*k);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code does not use generics which has the disadvantage that you will need to cast items to their actual type if you want to use methods that are not defined in the base class.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix(5, 5, new Matrix.NamedCellProducer());
ICell cell = m.get(0,0);
if (cell instanceof NamedCell) {
    String name = ((NamedCell)cell).getName();
}
```

Comment: This looks very close to what I am looking for. If the original initialization of the array uses an interface for cell like `ICell c[][] = new Cell[xCols][yRows];`, can I return a a different implementor?

Comment: `ICell c[][] = new ICell[x][y]; c[0][0] = new SpecialCell();` works as long a `SpecialCell` implements the `ICell` interface. If you do `ICell c[][] = new Cell[xCols][yRows]; c[0][0] = new Cell2();` where `Cell2` does not extend `Cell` but still implements `ICell` you get an `ArrayStoreException`

Comment: @anthropomo in case you want it with generics take a look at http://pastebin.com/wVKUBHqH

Comment: My way around generics is just doing this in the constructor: `wMatrix = (WaveCell[][]) matrix;`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of handling this.

---

**One Matrix Implementation, One Cell Implementation**

The least desirable, in my opinion, if you just have the one 'customizable' property on your Cell class, is to simply pass the property into the constructor of your Matrix class, in order to be used during the population call.

```
public Matrix(String cellName, int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height){
    matrix = populateCells(cellName, xCols,yRows);
    // ...
}

public Cell[][] populateCells(String cellName, int xCols, int yRows) {
    // ...
}
```

This method barely counts as object oriented programming, and becomes extremely difficult to maintain the more 'customizable' behavior you identify for your Cell class. Not recommended.

---

**Multiple Matrix Implementations**

Alternatively, you can create a hierarchy of Matrix classes, with an abstract superclass containing the core behavior, and specialized subclasses capable of populating their own cell types more appropriately.

```
public abstract class Matrix<T extends Cell> {

    private public T matrix[][];

    public Matrix(int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height){
        matrix = populateCells(xCols,yRows);
        // ...
    }

    public T[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) ;
}

public class RedBloodCellMatrix extends Matrix<RedBloodCell> {

    @Override
    public RedBloodCell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Nothing wrong with this method, its a classic multiple inheritance strategy.

---

Yet another option, which in my opinion is preferable, is to consider the population of cells as being pluggable, ***strategic*** behavior that you can plug in to the Matrix class at runtime. This method can be considered an implementation of the [composition-over-inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle:

```
public class Matrix {

    private public Cell matrix[][];
    private CellPopulationStrategy cellPopulationStrategy;
    // ...

    public Matrix(CellPopulationStrategy strategy, int xCols, int yRows, float width, float height){
        matrix = populateCells(strategy, xCols,yRows);
        // ...
    }

    public Cell[][] populateCells(CellPopulationStrategy strategy, int xCols, int yRows) {
        return strategy.populateCells(xCols, yRows);
    }
}

public interface CellPopulationStrategy {
    public Cell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows);
}

public RedBloodCellPopulationStrategy implements CellPopulationStrategy{

    @Override
    public Cell[][] populateCells(int xCols, int yRows) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is an excellent method to use as it scales very well with object complexity (particularly when you want to override behavior for more than one encapsulated object.

Comment: If I am reading this right (high likelihood I am not), it seems the strategy gets me back to square one.  Won't `populateCells` in every implementor still need to rehash all the code in the original "Matrix" class, assuming they all need x, y, and num?

Comment: No, just the logic in the populateCells method. Which, if needed you can create a base class for your strategy class that implements most of the populate logic, but *defers* creation of a new cell to concrete implementations (think `getNewCell()`).

Comment: I'll be back to +1 this when I can (Yay, 11 points!).  I appreciate the thoroughness and depth, but I think I prefer the relative simplicity of @zapi's answer. Plus, I don't think the Cell classes should "know" about the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to make the constructor public Cell(int x, int y, int num) working in all derived class. Please, see the example below – it is based on the protected init method.

```
public class Cell {
protected int x, y, num;

public Cell() {
}

public Cell(int x, int y, int num) {
    init(x, y, num);
}

protected void init(int x, int y, int num) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.num = num;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}
}

public class CellWithName extends Cell {
protected String name;

public CellWithName(int x, int y, int num, String name) {
    init(x, y, num);
    this.name = name;
}
}
```